# Embedded Database project

Tags: java, database

So I received this error message:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException
>   : Error connecting to server localhost on port

What does this even mean? I searched it up and what I found was that I never created an embedded database but rather a server? Regardless, the steps I followed were exact in order to create an embedded database.

Comment: Can you share some code you have written

Comment: What steps did you follow. What does your config looks like currently?